# Interpreting odds ratios

Tags: r, odds-ratio

I have the following set of results for one of the factors (birth weight) with different levels and their corresponding Odds ratios for survival. I am using the first level (<1.25) as the reference level:

Birth weight (kg):

```
Levels      Number/level    Odds Ratio
<1.25       1615            1.00
1.25-1.46   1617            1.37
1.46-1.65   1462            1.25
1.65-1.87   1632            1.68
>1.87       1466            2.35
```

From this result, I am trying to estimate, by using the OR, the approximate number of newborns that would survive in each level.

Are there ways that this can be achieved using R?

In a separate calculation, the actual number of survival per level are shown below:

```
Levels      Number/level    Odds Ratio    Actual number survived
<1.25       1615            1.00         1088
1.25-1.46   1617            1.37         1346
1.46-1.65   1462            1.25         1238
1.65-1.87   1632            1.68         1447
>1.87       1466            2.35         1351
```

EDIT:
The above is just one of the independent factors from my model.

```
mod <- glm(formula = surv ~ as.factor(var1) + as.factor(var2)+...as.factor(varn)+family = binomial(link = "logit"), data=mydf)


summary(mod)

glm(formula = surv ~ as.factor(season) + as.factor(bwt5) + as.factor(prectem5) + 
    as.factor(pcscore) + as.factor(pindx5) + as.factor(presp2) + 
    as.factor(ppscore) + as.factor(mtone2) + as.factor(fos) + 
    as.factor(psex) + as.factor(pscolor) + as.factor(pshiv) + 
    as.factor(backfat5) + as.factor(srect2) + as.factor(gest3) + 
    as.factor(int3) + as.factor(agit) + as.factor(tacc), family = binomial(link = "logit"), 
    data = lesna)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-3.0562   0.3120   0.4478   0.5929   1.9412  

Coefficients:
                      Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)           1.441842   0.290536   4.963 6.95e-07 ***
as.factor(season)2   -1.064053   0.107666  -9.883  < 2e-16 ***
as.factor(bwt5)2      0.314332   0.099776   3.150 0.001631 ** 
as.factor(bwt5)3      0.223824   0.110566   2.024 0.042935 *  
as.factor(bwt5)4      0.524586   0.120182   4.365 1.27e-05 ***
as.factor(bwt5)5      0.854196   0.138993   6.146 7.97e-10 ***
as.factor(prectem5)2  0.745025   0.094238   7.906 2.66e-15 ***
as.factor(prectem5)3  0.856777   0.098326   8.714  < 2e-16 ***
as.factor(prectem5)4  0.997219   0.111529   8.941  < 2e-16 ***
as.factor(prectem5)5  0.930925   0.120052   7.754 8.88e-15 ***
as.factor(pcscore)2   0.384534   0.137564   2.795 0.005185 ** 
as.factor(pcscore)3   0.668390   0.154608   4.323 1.54e-05 ***
as.factor(pindx5)2    0.243485   0.101755   2.393 0.016718 *  
as.factor(pindx5)3    0.262779   0.108809   2.415 0.015733 *  
as.factor(pindx5)4    0.595672   0.118124   5.043 4.59e-07 ***
as.factor(pindx5)5    0.467277   0.120401   3.881 0.000104 ***
as.factor(presp2)2   -0.286214   0.126012  -2.271 0.023127 *  
as.factor(ppscore)2  -0.246369   0.093568  -2.633 0.008462 ** 
as.factor(mtone2)2   -0.482397   0.118218  -4.081 4.49e-05 ***
as.factor(fos)2      -0.255652   0.075749  -3.375 0.000738 ***
as.factor(psex)2      0.182437   0.066964   2.724 0.006442 ** 
as.factor(pscolor)2  -0.694197   0.282069  -2.461 0.013852 *  
as.factor(pshiv)2    -0.241515   0.080792  -2.989 0.002796 ** 
as.factor(backfat5)2 -0.309427   0.104176  -2.970 0.002976 ** 
as.factor(backfat5)3 -0.004152   0.108669  -0.038 0.969523    
as.factor(backfat5)4  0.013233   0.103491   0.128 0.898257    
as.factor(backfat5)5 -0.221935   0.104639  -2.121 0.033926 *  
as.factor(srect2)2   -0.236981   0.104962  -2.258 0.023960 *  
as.factor(gest3)2     0.207375   0.106065   1.955 0.050562 .  
as.factor(gest3)3     0.904959   0.191307   4.730 2.24e-06 ***
as.factor(int3)2     -0.204870   0.127674  -1.605 0.108573    
as.factor(int3)3     -1.271092   0.388924  -3.268 0.001082 ** 
as.factor(agit)2     -0.496856   0.157553  -3.154 0.001613 ** 
as.factor(agit)3     -0.360247   0.148520  -2.426 0.015284 *  
as.factor(tacc)2     -0.282180   0.090556  -3.116 0.001833 ** 
as.factor(tacc)3     -0.429249   0.082520  -5.202 1.97e-07 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 7096.2  on 7791  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 6143.0  on 7756  degrees of freedom
AIC: 6215

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 5

exp(mod$coefficients) # odds ratios
         (Intercept)   as.factor(season)2     as.factor(bwt5)2 
           4.2284770            0.3450544            1.3693441 
    as.factor(bwt5)3     as.factor(bwt5)4     as.factor(bwt5)5 
           1.2508506            1.6897596            2.3494840 
as.factor(prectem5)2 as.factor(prectem5)3 as.factor(prectem5)4 
           2.1064944            2.3555559            2.7107340 
as.factor(prectem5)5  as.factor(pcscore)2  as.factor(pcscore)3 
           2.5368547            1.4689297            1.9510940 
  as.factor(pindx5)2   as.factor(pindx5)3   as.factor(pindx5)4 
           1.2756866            1.3005395            1.8142499 
  as.factor(pindx5)5   as.factor(presp2)2  as.factor(ppscore)2 
           1.5956440            0.7511016            0.7816335 
  as.factor(mtone2)2      as.factor(fos)2     as.factor(psex)2 
           0.6173022            0.7744113            1.2001382 
 as.factor(pscolor)2    as.factor(pshiv)2 as.factor(backfat5)2 
           0.4994756            0.7854368            0.7338673 
as.factor(backfat5)3 as.factor(backfat5)4 as.factor(backfat5)5 
           0.9958568            1.0133207            0.8009678 
  as.factor(srect2)2    as.factor(gest3)2    as.factor(gest3)3 
           0.7890065            1.2304445            2.4718305 
    as.factor(int3)2     as.factor(int3)3     as.factor(agit)2 
           0.8147530            0.2805250            0.6084405 
    as.factor(agit)3     as.factor(tacc)2     as.factor(tacc)3 
           0.6975039            0.7541382            0.6509975 

exp(coef(mod)) #exponentiated coefficients
exp(confint(mod)) # 95% CI
```

RUNNING THE SCRIPT WITHOUT type="response"

```
> (pred1s <- predict(mod,newdata=as.data.frame(with(lesna,list(season=1,bwt5=1,
+            prectem5=1,pcscore=1,pindx5=1,presp2=1,ppscore=1,mtone2=1 .... [TRUNCATED] 
       1 
1.441842
```

RUNNING THE SCRIPT WITH type="response":

```
> (pred1s <- predict(mod,newdata=as.data.frame(with(lesna,list(season=1,bwt5=1,
+            prectem5=1,pcscore=1,pindx5=1,presp2=1,ppscore=1,mtone2=1 .... [TRUNCATED] 
        1 
0.8087397
```

Comment: If you do not show either the model coefficients from which these ORs were calculated, in particular the "Intercept", or show the data of deaths and alives, then there will not be much in the way of definitive advice.

Comment: @DWin, I have just edited my question.

Comment: I modified my answer and included `type="response" to yield predicted probabilities.

Comment: @DWin: I ran the script without and with type="response". The first one gave me 1.441842 which is the same as the intercept of the coefficients from summary(mod); the second one gave 0.8087397.

Comment: The first one is the log(odds) estimate (and it should equal the Intercept since that is what the Intercept represents), while the second one is the estimated survival for a piglet with those features.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fact that these are coefficients are represented entirely by factors in R means that the Intercept is the log-odds for the event, i.e log(the proportion with event / proportion without) for subjects who all have their factor values at the lowest level. We know that of the 1615 in level 1 of the factor under scrutiny, 1088  survived, although 1088/(1615-1088) (= odds of survival given factor =1) is not necessarily going to match up with exp(Intercept) since not all of those people also had the other factors at the lowest level. In fact the odds of survival (or it could be death, since it's not really been made clear what the coding for the events was) was quite different. At the best case of all factors being = 1 the odds of survival were:

```
exp( 4.2284770 )
[1] 68.61266
```

That's actually a pretty low odds for newborn survival, so this must have been a NICU study or something happening in a third world county. But its way higher than the odds for all children who had that value and any other values for the other predictors. (When looking at the single line of data it was neither ... it was on a different species.)  In R the way to get a quick estimate of survival probability would be:

```
 (pred1s <- predict(mod, newdata=as.data.frame( with( lesna, 
   list( seas = 1 , 
        btw=1 , prectem5 =1 , 
        pcscore =1 , pindx5 =1 ,
        presp2= 1 ,   ppscore=  1,
        mtone2 = , fos =  , 
        psex =  1 , pscolor = 1, 
        pshiv =1 ,    backfat5= 1 , 
        srect2 =levels(srect2)[1] , gest3 =1 , 
        int3= 1 , agit= 1 , tacc =1 ) )
                               ), 
      type="response"  )
)        # the outer parens are to get a value to print when the assignment is made
```

You *can* the compare exp(Intercept) to that ( atypical ) prediction divided by (1-prediction) ... since that what odds are. So I hope it's becoming clear. You need to specify all of the factor level values at once to get a prediction. Or you need to create a synthetic cohort with a specific composition of all factor levels. You *cannot* take a single factor distribution and create a prediction from such a complex model *unless* you specify some sort of average value for all the other factors.

## Edit after looking at the single line of data:

Some (most in fact) of those variable were not factors, (and I guess I should have recognized that), which means they do not have any levels in your dataframe, but do have levels in the model matrix. I had assumed that the levels would be attributes of the factor variable, but I was wrong. It's going to be easier to work on this model if the structure of your 'newdata' arguments given to `predict` have the same structure as the original dataframe and I would seriously consider making a copy and turning all those items into factors. But with the exception of "srect2" we can change all of those items to 1. at least under the assumption that that is the minimum value for each of those variables. If it's not, ... then you need to use the minimum value. Code edited.

response value calculated:

1.4418   is the log-odds  ( the Intercept in the linear predictor fpr the baseline category)

odds = Pr(X=1)/(1-Pr(X=1))  :: definition

log(odds) = log(Pr(X=1)/(1-Pr(X=1)) ) = 1.4418  :: starting point

Solve for Pr(X=1) ... *should* be =  the calculated "response" value.

exp(1.4418)*(1- Pr(X=1) ) = Pr(X=1)

exp(1.4418) = (1+exp(1.4418))* Pr(X=1)

Pr(X=1) = exp(1.4418) / (1+exp(1.4418))

```
> exp(1.4418) / (1+exp(1.4418))
[1] 0.8087332
```

All of the other levels need to have the Intercept added to get their correct linear predictors. The *difference* in log-odds, i.e. the coefficients,  is directly equivalent to the *ratio* on the odds scale, hence the exp(coef) is a bunch of odds ratios.

```
{ log(x-y) = c  }    <=>      { x/y = exp(c) }
```

--

Comment: thank you so much for that. I still have two issues: i) I tried to run the above script and it me this message "Error in data.frame(season = NULL, bwt5 = NULL, prectem5 = NULL, pcscore = NULL,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 1" ii) when you said that "You need to specify all of the factor level values at once to get a prediction": where should i indicate the level values?

Comment: Can you post `dput(lesna[1,])`? That will have all the the factor structure needed to make a correct argument to `newdata`.

Comment: is it posible to send it to your email. I can not post it "dput(lesna[1,])" here as it is too huge.

Comment: Surely: dwinsemius [at] comcast [dot] net

Comment: i have sent the output file to your email address.

Comment: I ran the script: > (pred1s <- predict(mod,newdata=as.data.frame(with(lesna,list(season=1,bwt5=1,
+            prectem5=1,pcscore=1,pindx5=1,presp2=1,ppscore=1,mtone2=1 .... [TRUNCATED] and it gave me this:
        1 
0.8087397

Comment: Success.......!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/5896/discussion-between-baz-and-dwin)

Answer (score 4):

Odds *ratios* are a measure of difference in rate between two groups. So, it doesn't make sense to talk about just the "odds ratio" for a single group, you have to say what you're comparing that group with.

You might find it easier to start with more fundamental quantity, odds - actually this is just another way of expressing probability. The *odds* of an event is the probability it happens divided by the probability it does not happen. So, if the probability of an event happening is 0.8 (i.e. 80%) then its odds are 0.8/0.2=4.

In your example, I'm not totally certain what "Number" means - is is the number of infants, or the number of infants who survived? From your first table, to calculate what you want, you'll need the Odds in (at least) one group, not just Odds Ratios.

Finally, if this is homework, could you add a homework tag?

Comment: Once you have odds you can use the command plogis(log(odds)) to extract the probability and multiply the probability by number (if number is the total number of infants) to extract the expected number who survived.

Comment: @guest: I did not mention that the first level (birth weight<1.25kg) was used as the reference level. Further, it ws not mentioned that this is part of a research work (not home work) which involved newborn piglets and the producers would be more interested in hearing the number that would survive in each category than just odds ratios only. That was my main reason of tryong to relate OR to number survived.

Comment: @drknexus. Is it possible to re-visit this post? I am interested in your comment above and would like a little bit help.

Comment: @baz: Sure, or you could ask a fresh question.

Comment: guest, can you confirm that this [other account](http://stats.stackexchange.com/users/7516/guest) is yours?

Comment: @chl, yes, that's me. Sorry about the confusion

Comment: Ok, no problem. I've merged your two accounts. I would suggest you [register](http://stats.stackexchange.com/faq#login) this one.

Comment: The point that odds ratios are always a comparison across groups or distinct values of a continuous variable is correct. Saying that odds ratios are "differences in rates" is imprecise language in two ways: 1) they are not differences but rather ratios, and 2) they are not ratios of rates but rather ratios of odds. Rates have a time component. They are events/number_at_risk/time. Odds are just proportion_positive/ proportion_negative. In the case where all subjects have been observed for similar periods AND the event rates are low, then the odds-ratios will be similar to the rate-ratios.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the predicted probability of survival from a logistic regression program. In R, `fitted()` gives you fitted probabilities for each person. Your code would be something like:

```
model1 <- glm(survival~birthweight, family = binomial)
fitted(model1)
```

And you can extract from that the value for different birthweights.

Alternatively, you can get the coefficients of the model (use `coef()` in R) and then use the formula

$\pi(x) = \frac{e^{(\beta_0 + \beta_1 X_1 + e)}} {e^{(\beta_0 + \beta1 X_1 + e)} + 1} = \frac {1} {e^{-(\beta_0 + \beta_1 X_1 + e)} + 1}$

where the $\beta$ are the coefficients and the $X$ are the variables (you will need to adjust it if you have more than one independent variable)

Comment: Or alternatively, we can use `predict()`, with `type="response"` to get individual probabilities (instead of log-odds values). I don't think you want to include an error term when computing $\hat\pi(\beta'x_i)$.